# Why are table and tbody's scrollHeight > clientHeight for stackoverflow questions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Was making a function to list the parent scrollable element of a given node and using this check

```
( e.scrollWidth > e.clientWidth ) || ( e.scrollHeight > e.clientHeight )
```

and as I tested it on the page I had open ( a stackoverflow question ) I noticed that the `<table>` and `<tbody>` elements for questions and answers return `true`. This doesn't happen for the other `<table>` and `<tbody>` elements on the page.

My initial **guess** was borders or margins, but it doesn't seem to be the case (as demonstrated by below code, try it on this page).

What is going on to cause this and how would I check for it?

---

```
var tbodys = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody'), css,
    i = tbodys.length;
while( i-- > 0 ) console.log(
                     tbodys[i],
                     tbodys[i].scrollHeight > tbodys[i].clientHeight,
                     (css = window.getComputedStyle( tbodys[i] )).border,
                     css.margin,
                     css.padding,
                     css.position,
                     css.top
                 );
```

I don't know if this is applicable to all browsers, just Google Chrome or something even more specific.

Comment: You've found the perfect meta + non-meta question.